# Invalid character found in the request target spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the following URL with array query param

```
http://127.0.0.1:3009/mac/view/:userId?ot-replace[0]=kin43
```

This is my controller code

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{userId}/**")
public ResponseEntity<String> viewObject(@PathVariable(value = "userId") String uId, HttpServletRequest request,
                                         @RequestParam(name="ot-replace", required=false)String[] regexReplace ) {}
```

I get the following error

```
 Invalid character found in the request target The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
```

What is wrong over here?

Update :

After allowing the special character for tomcat

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=[,]
```

I don't get that error but still I receive `regexReplace` as `null`

Answer (score 0):

I guess colon(before user id) is not valid.
try removing that

[http://127.0.0.1:3009/mac/view/:userId?ot-replace[0]=kin43](http://127.0.0.1:3009/mac/view/:userId?ot-replace%5B0%5D=kin43)

Comment: `:` defines path variable in an API